# Retrieve database server from connection URL

Tags: regex, ant

I am using ant script and I have following requirement.

- If input -
  jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\MSSQLSERVER2016;databaseName=DBNAME then
  output - **localhost\\MSSQLSERVER2016**
- If input - jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=DBNAME
  then ouptut - **localhost**

With the below code I am only getting **localhost**. Is the above requirment is possible with regex? Can anyone help me on this?

```
<propertyregex property="database.server" input="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\MSSQLSERVER2016;databaseName=DBNAME" regexp=".*\\(.[a-z\-0-9,.:])" select="\1" casesensitive="false" />enter code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the regexp you're looking for:

```
jdbc:sqlserver:\/\/(.+)?;
```

Test: https://regex101.com/r/4NjitD/1

Comment: Working! The exact thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex:

```
://([a-zA-Z0-9\\]+)
```